# Colapsar al pulsar sobre menu

Tags: menú, nav

Me gustaría que al pulsar sobre alguna opción del menú, este se colapsara.

Dejo el código Html, Css y un enlace para probar el código.

```
Html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>NavSlide</title>

        <!-- FontAwesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!-- Google Web Fonts -->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,300italic,400italic,500italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- The CSS -->
        <link href="css/navslide.css" rel="stylesheet" />


        <!-- This js is used for the menu works in older browsers -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

    </head>

    <body>

        <nav class="menu-container">
            <a href="#" class="menu-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i></a>
            <div class="menu-slide">
                <ul class="menu-list">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Documentation</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </body>

</html>
```

El Css:

```
/* Generated by less 2.4.0 */
/* Create by: Felipe Dumont
/* Version: 1.0
/* Website: www.darkmedia.com.br


/* Colors */
/* Animations */
.transition-2s {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
/* Menu */
.menu-container:hover .menu-slide {
  -o-transform: translate(270px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(270px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(270px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(270px, 0);
  transform: translate(270px, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.menu-container .menu-btn {
  color: #333333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: :10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10000;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-container .menu-btn:hover {
  color: #666666;
}
.menu-container .menu-slide {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  height: 100%;
  left: -270px;
  top: 0;
  width: 270px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 10000;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 6s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu-container .menu-slide .menu-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu-container .menu-slide .menu-list .menu-item a {
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333333;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.menu-container .menu-slide .menu-list .menu-item a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #333;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

El enlace para ver el código funcionando.

```
http://www.cubicfactory.com/jseditor/welcome/102060/edit
```

He intentado llamar a una funcion en el en el a Href de los enlaces, y en esa funcion hacer desaparecer el div.

```
$(".menu-slide").hide();
```

Efectivamente .menu-slide desaparece pero ya no vuelve a aparecer otra vez cuando pongo el cursor encima. Creo que la unica forma es usando css algo parecido a esto pero cuando se haga click sobre la clase correspondiente.

function cierra(){
 $(".menu-container .menu-slide").css(
     {'left: -270px;'}

```
);
```

}

Respecto a poner el codigo en un snippet no tengo idea de como hacerlo, buscare en el foro y la pròxima vez lo haré con snippet.

Comment: Hola Lorenzo. ¿Qué problemas tienes? ¿Qué has intentado?  Sobre tus fallos o problemas, podemos ayudarte a mejorarlo pero si no lo has intentado has de investigar y probar. Edita la pregunta añadiendo lo que has probado siguiendo [ask] y [mcve] (prueba tambien a poner el codigo en un snippet aqui para no tener que ejecutar HTML+CSS en otra pagina, es el icono `<>`). Un saludo

Comment: En tu ejemplo del enlace, el menú se muestra y oculta via CSS. Cuando añades esa línea de código a los enlaces, sin embargo, ocultas el menú via Javascript, y aunque éste utiliza CSS, no es el mismo que el tuyo. De todos modos, ¿Qué tipo de enlaces vas a poner? Si no es una one-page ni cargas el contenido via AJAX, descubrirás que no tienes ningún problema cuando los enlaces sean reales.

Comment: Explicándome un poco mejor, tu CSS tiene dos estados para el menú: con ratón encima (:hover) y normal. No puedes modificar ese estado con Javascript, así que no hay una solución inmediata y en una línea como estás intentando. Podrías sustituir el estado "con ratón encima" con una clase, y dar o quitar dicha clase via eventos Javascript